# How to modify xml on wix repair

Tags: wix, installation

I have an installer that is created with `WIX` and modifies a config via [XmlFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlfile.html), however I believe that the Wix Util Extension does not perform these actions on repair. This is causing problems when trying to perform a self-healing installer. Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

By piecing together a bunch of sources I came up with the following:

```
<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus"/>
<SetProperty Id="REINSTALL" Value="ALL" After="AppSearch">
    <![CDATA[Installed AND REMOVE<>"ALL"]]>
</SetProperty>
```

Which forces a `REINSTALL = ALL` if it is not a remove or install

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar scenario.  Properties can be edited by the user through the UI, which are stored/loaded via the Registry and written to configuration files.  Beyond Justin's answer, Secure="yes" must be set on each property, or MSI will ignore it (the log will show "Ignoring disallowed property").